# How to build binary RPM for a target from a source RPM on a Host using rpmbuild

Tags: linux, ubuntu, x86-64, rpm, rpmbuild

I have to deploy RPM package on my target architecture which is an x86_64 hardware running Windriver Linux. I am using **rpmbuild** utility on my Host system which is an x86 32-bit 12.04 Ubuntu PC. However, I don't have cross-compiler installed on my Host. I have to generate RPM on my Host in such a way so that it can generate the binary when deployed on the target. As of now, I'm stuck as I find that directly running `rpm -ivh <source-rpm>` on the target doesn't create binary files. What are the other options in this situation . How can I make an RPM package for some target architecture without having a *Cross-Compiler* on my Host . All I have on Host machine are *Source files* and a *Makefile* plus the *rpmbuild* utility. My target hardware has the necessary **gcc** and **make** tools for compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who may get stuck in the similar situation, I was able to solve this issue using FPM package management utility,which can be downloaded from the below github repo -

https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm

After successfully installing the FPM,one can see a list of various arguments which are useful here . One of such arguments is `--after-install` . Passing this argument with a script allows us to do some operation after the installation of the RPM package. And those operations are defined in the script . So, basically I defined my build statements inside this script. So this script would perform the necessay `make` and `make install` on the target once the package is installed using `rpm -ivh <package-name>` on the target.

The FPM command which I used to create the RPM package on my Host machine is as follows -

`fpm -s dir -t rpm -n <package-name> -a all -v 1.0.0 -C <path-of-Source-file-directory> --post-install <path-to-the-script-for-make> --before-remove <path-to-another-script-for-make clean> --prefix <path-for-downloading-package>` .

I know this is just a workaround. But if anyone else has a better way of doing it, then please do let me know.